# App break after upgrade from Angular 16 to Angular 17 - TransferHttpCacheModule

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

After migrating to Angular 17, the app.module.ts is breaking :(

'@nguniversal/common' has been replaced by '@angular/ssr', however the TransferHttpCachModule has this error Module '"@angular/ssr"' has no exported member 'TransferHttpCacheModule'.ts(2305).

Below the app.module.ts :
***UPDATE***

```
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CarouselComponent } from './carousel/carousel.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
/*MATERIAL*/
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatSliderModule as MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSnackBarModule as MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
/**/
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common'
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth.interceptor';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ResetComponent } from './reset/reset.component';
import { EulaComponent } from './eula/eula.component';
import { PrivacyComponent } from './privacy/privacy.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { WorksComponent } from './works/works.component';
import { FoundryComponent } from './foundry/foundry.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { FoundryDetailsComponent } from './foundry-details/foundry-details.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { GoogleMapsModule } from '@angular/google-maps';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project/project.component';
import { ValidateEqualModule } from 'ng-validate-equal';
import { UserMenuComponent } from './user-menu/user-menu.component';
import { SelectorComponent } from './selector/selector.component';
import { ShoppingCartItemComponent } from './shopping-cart-item/shopping-cart-item.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout/checkout.component';
import { CheckComponent } from './check/check.component';
import { NgxStripeModule } from 'ngx-stripe';
import { environment as env } from '../environments/environment';
import { FoundryGridComponent } from './foundry-grid/foundry-grid.component';
import { FaqComponent } from './faq/faq.component';
import { FoundryFontComponent } from './foundry-font/foundry-font.component'
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { FoundryTrialComponent } from './foundry-trial/foundry-trial.component';
import { FoundryListComponent } from './foundry-list/foundry-list.component';
import { GuideComponent } from './guide/guide.component';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import { SelectComponent } from './select/select.component'
import { MultiComponent } from './multi/multi.component';
import { PersonalComponent } from './personal/personal.component';
import { OrdersComponent } from './orders/orders.component';
import { InvoicesComponent } from './invoices/invoices.component';
import { PasswordComponent } from './password/password.component';
import { SuccessComponent } from './success/success.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { FoundryIsAddedIntoCartPipe } from './pipes/foundry-is-added-into-cart.pipe';
import { WebpPipe } from './webp.pipe';
import { PhotographyComponent } from './photography/photography.component';
import { FilterByTypePipe } from './filter-by-type.pipe';
import { VideoHoverDirective } from './video-hover.directive';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';


registerLocaleData(localeFr);


export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>) = null;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ResetComponent,
    EulaComponent,
    PrivacyComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    WorksComponent,
    FoundryComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    FoundryDetailsComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent,
    ProjectComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
    UserMenuComponent,
    SelectorComponent,
    ShoppingCartItemComponent,
    CheckoutComponent,
    CheckComponent,
    FoundryGridComponent,
    FaqComponent,
    FoundryFontComponent,
    FoundryTrialComponent,
    FoundryListComponent,
    GuideComponent,
    SelectComponent,
    MultiComponent,
    PersonalComponent,
    OrdersComponent,
    InvoicesComponent,
    PasswordComponent,
    SuccessComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    FoundryIsAddedIntoCartPipe,
    WebpPipe,
    PhotographyComponent,
    FilterByTypePipe,
    VideoHoverDirective,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    NgxStripeModule.forRoot(env.stripeKey),
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    OverlayModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    GoogleMapsModule,
    ValidateEqualModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [

    DatePipe,
    {
      provideClientHydration(),
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can a Angular 17 expert help me to migrate ?

I saw that there is no more module needed for angular 17, how can I smoothly remove the app.module.ts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TransferHttpCachModule` is now provided when using the hydration features.

You will need to add `provideClientHydration()` to your providers.

Comment: Still this error : Value at position 31 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference
  Value could not be determined statically.(-991010)
app.module.ts(158, 5): Unknown reference.

Comment: You need to remove that import.

Comment: If I remove the BrowserModule import the error goes to the next one : Value at position 31 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference
  Value could not be determined statically.(-991010)
app.module.ts(158, 5): Unknown reference.
(alias) class NgxStripeModule
import NgxStripeModule 
in fact this error is in everly modules imported in imports array

Comment: No, you need to remove the 31st import. The one before are fine.

Comment: Thank you Matthieu, it seems that the issue was coming from NGX-MASK. By following the new document in NPM site it worked. Thanks